# JQuery ajax error handler not called

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I'm trying to upload image with a call to jQuery's ajax() method into flask application. It works fine while file size is below maximum allowed file size. When file is larger that allowed, flask produces 413 (entity too large) error, but $.ajax() does not fire any event in this case: Safari's debugger shows that request is being executed.

Here is my ajax call:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#upload-form')[0]);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/upload_handler/",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log(data);
        $('#upload-form')[0].reset();
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert('error!');
    }
});
```

Flask's handler is not called because request is rejected earlier.

Again, ajax fails to handle error, success is successfully handled.
I'm using Safari 9, jQuery 2.4.1 and Flask 0.10.1.

Here is minimal working example:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 32 * 1024


@app.route('/upload/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_handler():
    if 'image' in request.files:
        img = request.files['image']
        return jsonify(name=img.filename, size=0)
    return jsonify(name='no', size=0)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html', now=datetime.datetime.now())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="uploadform" method="POST" action="{{      url_for('upload_handler') }}">
            <input type="file" name="image" >
            <button type="button" id="submit">Upload</button>

            <p>Result Filename:&nbsp;<span id="resultFilename"> here</span></p>
            <p>Result Filesize:&nbsp;<span id="resultFilesize">here</span></p>

            {{ now }}
        </form>

        <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#submit').click(function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                var form_data = new FormData($('#uploadform')[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "{{ url_for('upload_handler') }}",
                    data: form_data,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log('Success!');
                    $("#resultFilename").text(data['name']);
                    $("#resultFilesize").text(data['size']);
                    $('#uploadform')[0].reset();
                }).fail(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('error!');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

If one tries to upload file smaller than 32K it will show file's name, if one tries to upload larger file than nothing will happen, but flask will output log message with 413 code.

Comment: `flask produces 413 (entity too large) error, but $.ajax() does not fire any event in this case`. Can you clarify this line? Are you saying that neither the success nor the error handler are fired in this case?

Comment: Yes, entirely nothing happens: no messages at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `statusCode` to `$.ajax()` settings or `$.ajaxSetup()` to determine if error response does return `413` status code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  statusCode: {
    413: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I did it, but it seems that the function is not called: no message shown

Comment: @Xanx What are response headers at `Network` tab at `console` ?

Comment: There is no response - network tab says that requests are being executed, and it seems it may take much time

Comment: @Xanx Try aborting request if response not returned in `n` seconds to call `error` handler for `$.ajax()`

Comment: If I set timeout then error handler is called. But it seems strange to me: why it ignores error that is produces by flask? If I deliberately abort request with the same error code (413) then it is handled

Comment: _"why it ignores error that is produces by flask? If I deliberately abort request with the same error code (413) then it is handled"_ Not certain ? Check server configuration ?